# Can I use istream_iterator<char> to copy some istream content into std::string?

Tags: c++, stdstring, istream, istream-iterator, input-iterator

I have an `istream` and need to copy the content between two delimiters to a `std::string`.
I can find the delimiters' `streampos`, but when trying to use `istream_iterator<char>` to iterate over the section of the stream, it does not work. Here's what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>


std::string copyToString( std::istream& is )
{
    is >> std::ws;

    auto someLength {10};

    std::istream_iterator<char> beg {is};

    is.seekg( someLength, std::ios::cur );

    //std::istream_iterator<char> end { is };
    std::istream_iterator<char> end { std::next(beg, someLength) };

    return std::string{ beg, end };
}




int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.str( "   { my string content  }" );

    std::cout << "\"" << copyToString( ss ) << "\"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be 10 chars long, but it's just `"{"`. If I uncomment the line `std::istream_iterator<char> end { is };` and comment out the next one, the output is just `""`.

What am I missing? Can I not use iterators like that?

I am aware that I could create a `char[]` as a buffer, copy it to that, etc., but that seems much less straightforward.

Comment: fwiw, when I run your code I get a segfault https://wandbox.org/permlink/zhPnYCFQtzAn3MiK

Comment: `std::next(beg, someLength)` reads 10 characters from the stream. (However, I don't know how to do this correctly.)

Comment: @immibis: I believe you are mistaken: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/next/?kw=next

Comment: I'm not quite sure about input streams, but aren't you invalidating the `beg` iterator once you do `seekg`? I thought the point of these streams is that they do not keep their elements after they are passed?

Comment: You could instead do: `std::string result(someLength, ' '); is.read(&result[0], someLength); return result;`

Comment: @GeckoGeorge Thought about that, but my guess was that it's ```istream_iterator``` that you can't have going backwards, not the ```istream``` itself (which can totally do that).

Comment: @Eljay Apart from using resize(), that's precisely what I'm currently doing.

Comment: @RL-S "ForwardIterator shall be at least a forward iterator." - istream_iterator is an input iterator, which is less powerful than a forward iterator, so according to that documentation, using std::next on it is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::istream_iterator` is an *input iterator*.  Input iterators are single pass and are invalidated when copies thereof are incremented.  When you do `std::next(beg, someLength)`, you read `someLength` characters.  Then `beg` is invalidated.

Moreover, `std::istream_iterator` is not intended to be counted.  It is designed to be compared to a default constructed iterator, because of the way stream errors are handled.  If you attempt count them, then they will *sometimes* read one more time, depending on how the algorithm is implemented.

If you want to read `n` characters from an input stream, just use `read`.  If you want to skip spaces, then just write a loop.  If you want to use `std::istream_iterator` in an unintended way, then your code will fail unpredictably.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware that that is an unintended use, as it seems quite basic to me, and an otherwise typical use of iterators.

Comment: @RL-S Yeah, input iterators are quite restricted, to say the least.

Comment: But I actually also tried the default constructor ```std::istream_iterator<char> end;```. Why did that not work? Output was ```"{"``` IIRC.